# ListView not updating after async call

Tags: android

I have a weird / unique situation with my `ListView`. This is the scenario:

I'm making use of the MVP design pattern. As the `Activity` starts, it raises an event to notify the presenter to fetch some data from a web service. The web service call is an Async call. Once the web service `Completed` event is raised, I take the result and push it into a property (which is of type Array) that resides within my `View` / `Activity`.

Everything I mentioned works just fine, **but** as soon as the device is rotated, some interesting developments take place.

The async call resumes as normal and provides the property (Array) with a value. So nothing wrong there... (And yes there is data in the collection) I then set the `ListView Adapter` and call the `notifyDataSetChanged`, but nothing happens. The UI is not updated or anything?? If I re-enter the `Activity` the data is visible again ??

I even tried calling `invalidateViews` and `invalidate` on the `ListView` - this didn't do anything.

Could someone please assist me in this matter?
Many thanks in advance!

[Update]

I would like to stress the fact that I am making use of C# (Xamarin) and not Java (:sigh: - yes I know). Furthermore, I am not making use of the `ASyncTask` class, instead I'm making use of the async methods created within the proxy classes generated by Visual Studio. Pretty straight forward, but this is the code that populates the `ListView` - the property is set from the presenter

**Presenter**

*Where View is of type IContactsView*

```
    protected override void OnCollectData(System.Collections.IEnumerable data, Type typeOfData)
    {
        if (data != null && typeOfData != null && typeOfData.Equals(typeof(UserContact)))
        {
            this.View.UserInformationCollection = data.Cast<UserContact>().ToArray();
        }
    }
```

**Activity**

*The activity implements IContactsView*

```
    public UserContact[] UserInformationCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return this._userInformationCollection;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    this._userInformationCollection = value;                        
                    ListView listview = this.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.userLV);
                    if (listview != null)
                    {                           
                        UserContact[] subsidiesList = this.GetIndexedContacts(this._userInformationCollection);
                        listview.Adapter = new ContactsAdapter(this, subsidiesList.ToList());
                        ((ContactsAdapter)listview.Adapter).NotifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

[/Update]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a much better solution! So please ignore the `static variable` idea!

**Activity:**

Override the `OnRetainNonConfigurationInstance` and return the presenter

```
    public override Java.Lang.Object OnRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
    {
        return this._presenter;
    }
```

Within the `OnCreate` check the `LastNonConfigurationInstance` and get the presenter - if it isn't null:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        ...
        if (this.LastNonConfigurationInstance != null)
        {
            this._presenter = this.LastNonConfigurationInstance as ContactsPresenter;
            this._presenter.RefreshView(this);
        }
        else
        {
            // create a new presenter
            this._presenter = new ContactsPresenter(this);
        }
        ...
    }
```

So maybe, you saw what I did in the previous code sample? Yes, I send the new instance of the activity to the presenter - have a look at the `RefreshView`

**Presenter:**

So within my base presenter I have the following method:

```
public class Presenter<T> : Java.Lang.Object, IPresenter where T : IView
{
    /// <param name="view">The view.</param>
    public void RefreshView(T view)
    {
        this.View = view;
    }
}
```

The above code helps my presenter say with the creation of new activities - so when it returns data after the async call it will have the latest and greatest instance of the activity!

Hope this helps!
Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by doing the following:

declare a static variable of the activity:

```
    private static ContactsActivity _cachedActivity = null;
```

Overrode the `OnResume` within the activity and set the variable:

```
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        _cachedActivity = this;
    }
```

Override the `OnCreate` within the activity and set the variable:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        ...
        _cachedActivity = this;
        ...
    }
```

Lastly I changed the property mentioned earlier:

```
    public USBUserContact[] UserInformationCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return this._userInformationCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            _cachedActivity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    _cachedActivity._userInformationCollection = value;
                    ListView listview = _cachedActivity.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.userLV);
                    if (listview != null)
                    {
                        UserContact[] subsidiesList = _cachedActivity.GetIndexedContacts(_cachedActivity._userInformationCollection);
                        listview.Adapter = new ContactsAdapter(_cachedActivity, subsidiesList.ToList());
                        ((ContactsAdapter)listview.Adapter).NotifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

Kind regards,